# adding elements from previous list to current list in Python with enumerate

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['', 'melinda gates', '55']
```

where

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
```

Basically, I want the empty fields to be populated by the element in the same index from the previous list. How do I get my output to be as follows?

```
list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['amazon', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['amazon', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['microsoft', 'melinda gates', '55']
```

Comment: Your code does not include a list of lists, just 5 lists identified by 5 separate identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if any of the values are blank. Not just the first value.

```
list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['', 'melinda gates', '55']

lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]

for i, arr in enumerate(lists[1:]): # Just iterate through lists but from the the 2nd list. Not the first.
    for j in range(len(arr)): # Iterate through inner list
        if not arr[j]: # Means blank or None
            arr[j] = lists[i][j]  # Replace value with the previous list. Remember i points one less because we have started from 2nd list
for arr in lists:
    print(arr)

#Output
['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
['amazon', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
['amazon', 'preston bezos', '20']
['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
['microsoft', 'melinda gates', '55']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    if not l[0]:
        l[0] = lists[i-1][0]
```

Comment: If the first value in the first list is blank, this will replace it with the first value in the last list. That may be undesirable.

Comment: Your answer assumes the existence of an identifier `lists` which stores a list of the 5 lists in the OP's question. You did not state that this the case.

Comment: This is true, but the premise of forward-filling for a non-existent entry 0 in the 0th list in n lists, is kind of non-sensical anyway, so I'm not sure it matters that much. My answer assumes you will always have a first value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to keep track of the previous columns that have been seen, using the index as the key. Then update empty `''` values with the previous found value at that column. I'm assuming the previous value can be anything but `''`.

```
from pprint import pprint

list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['', 'melinda gates', '55']

lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]

prev_col_values = {}
for row, lst in enumerate(lists):
    for col, word in enumerate(lst):
        if not word:
            lists[row][col] = prev_col_values.get(col, '')
            continue    
        prev_col_values[col] = word

pprint(lists)
```

**Output:**

```
[['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56'],
 ['amazon', 'mackenzie bezos', '50'],
 ['amazon', 'preston bezos', '20'],
 ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64'],
 ['microsoft', 'melinda gates', '55']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def work(lists):
print("Before converting>>>\r\n")
print (lists)

tag_to_add = ''
for item in lists:
    if len(item[0]) > 0:
        tag_to_add = item[0]
    else:
        if len(tag_to_add) > 0:
            item[0] = tag_to_add

print ("After converting>>>\r\n")
print (lists)
```

Above is the code.

```
list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['', 'melinda gates', '55']

lists1 = [list1,list2,list3,list4,list5]
work(lists1)
```

above is test case 1

```
list1 = ['amazon', 'jeff bezos', '56']
list2 = ['', 'mackenzie bezos', '50']
list3 = ['', 'preston bezos', '20']
list4 = ['microsoft', 'bill gates', '64']
list5 = ['', 'melinda gates', '55']

lists1 = [list2,list1,list3,list4,list5]
work(lists1)
```

above is test case 2